# Как из плагина достать модель?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-cms

Модель

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/images/")
    content = HTMLField(blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(always_update=True,populate_from='title', unique=True) 
    date_created = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

Плагин

```
class PostPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Регистрация плагина

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class CMSPostPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PostPlugin
    name = _("Post")
    render_template = "post/post.html"
    allow_children = True
    admin_preview = True
    module = "subpage"

def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context.update({
        'post':instance.post,
        'instance':instance,
        'placeholder':placeholder
    })
    return context
```

Сформировалась промежуточная таблица, в которой к плагину привязывается модель из бд.
[image: Скриншот таблицы]

Вот таким образом достаю плагины:

```
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(plugin_type='CMSPostPlugin', placeholder_id=placehoder.id)
```

но как по plugin id достать с этой таблицы Post id?

Comment: Если я верно поняла, у вас Post привязан к PostPlugin, значит через модель PostPlugin  и надо делать запрос для получения id поста `PostPlugin.objects.get(...).post.id`

Comment: @Александр я пытался, но import error, т.к. я использую import *